# Display text in a responsive image and keeping margin left to 0

Tags: html, css

I have an image which responsive in width but with fixed height.

Inside this image, I want to display a text which must always have `margin-right:0;` relatively to the image itself.

This is what I have tried. But you can see that when you resize the window, I do not get exactly what I want.

**CSS:**

```
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
.imgStyle {
  width: 50%;
  max-width: 200px; 
  height:120px;
}
.txt {
  z-index: 100;
  position: absolute;
  right:26%;
  top: 70px;
  width: 50px;
  height:30px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class = 'wrapper'>
     <img src ='http://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg'
       class = 'imgStyle'
   >
    <p class = 'txt'>Hello</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Demo:**

http://jsbin.com/segudozomu/edit?html,css,output

**EDIT:**

In the real problem I have, I can not set the image itself as a background image for the text.

Comment: do you want to set the image as a background image for the .wrapper div or container div ??

Comment: No. I can not change the conception I have done (on the real problem, I am using an unknown Framework, this is a very simplified version of the real problem, but if I get a solution for this, I will for sure resolve my real problem)

Comment: with an extra-wrapper will be more easy http://jsbin.com/sufovumuna/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: You saved my life tonight @DaniP Thank you very much. If you post it as an answer I will accept it gracefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an extra wrapper you can position all the elements at the center and keep the relation `width` / `margin-right` of the img and text like this:

```css
.wrapper {
  left: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
.wrapper > div {
  width: 50%;
  max-width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}
.imgStyle {
  width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
}
.txt {
  z-index: 100;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 70px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div>
    <img src='http://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg' class='imgStyle'>
    <p class='txt'>Hello</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

make your **html and css** like this :

```css
.wrapper {
  left:10%;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
.imgStyle {
  max-width: 200px; 
  height:120px;
  width:100%;
}
.txt {
  z-index: 100;
  position: absolute;
  right:0;
  top: 70px;
  width: 50px;
  height:30px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.img-container{
  width:50%;
  display:table;
  margin:0 auto;
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class = 'wrapper'>
    <div class="img-container">
     <img src ='http://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg'
       class = 'imgStyle'
   >
    <p class = 'txt'>Hello</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, it almost works. Almost because when I resize the screen width above 869px, I do not get that effect

Comment: put max-width:200px for class .img-container and it works

Answer (score 0):

You may give a try to inline-block and vertical-align

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
.imgStyle {
  max-width: 200px;
  height: 120px;
}
.txt,
.imgStyle {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;/* update this value to your needs : top, middle, 2em, whatever you need */
  margin: 0;
}
.txt {
  /* optionnal
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  */
  background-color: yellow;
}
.img-container {
  display: table;/* shrinks on content and can be centered */
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class="img-container">
    <img src='http://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg' class='imgStyle'><!-- comment to erase white-space from inline-block element --><p class='txt'>Hello</p>
  </div>
</div>
```